# Synchronizing Jeweler's gem version with version string in program itself

Tags: ruby, rubygems, versioning

So I'm using [Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) to maintain a [little gem of mine](https://github.com/jpatokal/mediawiki-gateway), and it provides a set of handy `rake version:*` tasks for managing the version number.  Jeweler apparently stores the version number in a file called VERSION, which is then read on `rake gemspec`.  The only problem is, the actual Ruby code in the library *also* contains a version, which is eg. sent out in HTTP request headers created by the library:

```
module MediaWiki
  class << self
    def version
      "0.1.6"
    end
    ...
```

Any ideas for keeping these two in sync automatically?  Alternatively, is there some way the MediaWiki library can query the gem it was turned into to find its own version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you have the version method return a constant?

```
# lib/media_wiki/version.rb
module MediaWiki
  VERSION = "1.0.6"
end

# lib/media_wiki.rb (or wherever)
module MediaWiki
  class << self
    def version
      MediaWiki::VERSION
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT (in response to comment):

Also you have to update your Rakefile to use the constant:

```
# Rakefile
Jeweler::Tasks.new do |gemspec|
  ...
  gemspec.version     = MediaWiki::VERSION
  ...
end
```

Peer

Comment: I could, but how would that constant be kept in sync with Jeweler's version?

Comment: Edited the post to answer that.

Comment: Brilliant!  (And obvious in retrospect... sigh.)  I won't be able to use the rake version:bump:* tasks anymore, but that's by far the lesser of two evils.